# Error reading table in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python/Pandas and when I try to:

> df = pd.read_table("/test/" + file, sep='\t')

I get the error:

> 'Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 24 fields in line 6927, saw 26'

How do I overcome this?

Comment: Also try: `df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=r'\t')`. You're actually placing a tab there, not the character sequence `"\" + "t"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :-)

```
data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```